# How Do I make this sunburst start with the inner ring consuming the entire diameter of the chart?

Tags: d3.js, transition, sunburst-diagram

The Start of my visualization does not 'match' what I want it to.
The start of my sunburst does not consume the entire radius of the circle, instead only a partial diameter.

I'm trying to adapt an example, that uses hierarchical data, to my own iteration, that uses a flat json dataset (see example).

1. Convert flat json data to a hierarchical format (d3.stratify then d3.hierarchy)
2. make a dataJoin
3. draw the arcs

Source example: `https://bl.ocks.org/denjn5/3b74baf5edc4ac93d5e487136481c601`

My Current iteration
https://codepen.io/mretfaster/pen/LwjxGw

I expect the starting visualization to consume the entire diameter of the sunburst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `makeRoot` function and in `toggleOrder` you are doing `.sum(d => d.value)` replace it to `.sum(d => d.data.size)`.

`value` is generated by `d3` after calling `d3.hierarchy` and used by the `d3.partition` to get the angles. But `size` is the name of the values in your data source, and that is what `sum` expects.

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eqGzoX) is the updated codepen

Comment: Thanks! 
I think I was trying d.size, not d.data.size!